# finding is point laying on line or not in esri map using arcgis API

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

I am trying to find whether the point lies on the line or not as below

```
 function identifyFeatures(evt){
     var extentGeom = pointToExtent(map,evt.mapPoint,10);
     var filteredGraphics = dojo.filter(testLayer.graphics, function(gg) {
         if(extentGeom.contains(gg.geometry.getExtent())){
             return extentGeom.contains(gg.geometry.getExtent());
         } else {
             return gg.geometry.getExtent().contains(extentGeom);
         } 
      });
      var content = "";
      content = "<i>Total Features: " + filteredGraphics.length + "</i>";
      map.infoWindow.setContent(content);
      map.infoWindow.setTitle("Identify Results");
      var anchor = map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint);
      map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint,anchor);
 };
```

I am using **contains** method of extent and trying to check whether clicked 
point extent is falling on line extent or line extent is falling on clicked 
point extent.But if I click on the center of the line then only I am getting 
features. 
    You can see the code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poojamadiwal/s0r41L9k/)

can any one suggest me is there any other way to check whether point lies on line or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just filter graphics if the extent of the point (padded with your `extentToPoint()` function) [`intersects()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/extent-amd.html#intersects) with the geometry of the line.

```
  function identifyFeatures(evt){
      var extentGeom = pointToExtent(map,evt.mapPoint,10);
      var filteredGraphics = dojo.filter(testLayer.graphics, function(gg) {
        return extentGeom.intersects(gg.geometry);
      });
      var content = "<i>Total Features: " + filteredGraphics.length + "</i>";
      map.infoWindow.setContent(content);
      map.infoWindow.setTitle("Identify Results");
      map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint,map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
  };
```

see a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q68rzde2/1/